# Putting text next to boostrap input not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

So I have a form and I'm using the Bootstrap framework and on every input type of this form I want to have text on the left showing what the input is for but what happens the text gets above the input like this:

Picture of how forms looks like right now:
[image]

```
<div class="container">
        <br>
        <center> <h3> Jongere toevoegen </h3> </center>
        <br>
                <?php  echo form_open('index.php/Addjongere/Add_jongere'); ?>
            <form>
                <div class="form-group row">
                 <label>Roepnaam:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="roepnaam" id="roepnaam" placeholder="Roepnaam" type="text">
                </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                         <label>Tussenvoegsel:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="tussenvoegsel" id="tussenvoegsel" placeholder="Tussenvoegsel" type="text">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label>Achternaam:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="achternaam" id="achternaam" placeholder="Achternaam" type="text">
                </div>

                <div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" name="Add_jongere" >Toevoegen</button>
                </div>
            </form>       
        </div>
```

Does anyone know what I can do?
Any kind of help is appreciated

Comment: Have you tried [this example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#readonly-plain-text)?

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#horizontal-form look here, just change `<div class="form-group">` to `<div class="form-group row">`

Comment: @jeremy now the labels are not centered, they are all the way to the left of the page, how do I fix this?

Comment: Check my edited question, it shows how I have it right now

Comment: @Jeremy Check my answer, is this what you needed? I think just removing the `form-inline` now does the job.

Comment: No sir, check my latest picture in my question, that is how my form looks like right now, I also removed these class and id because it didn't do anything:   <div class="main2" id="addjongere">

Comment: @Jeremy *oh btw use `@jeremy` or react on my answer so I get a notification when you respond :)* , I edited my answer.. is this what you need?

Comment: The labels are next to the input type thx it works. But the only problem is now the input type have really big width right now.. just look at my updated picture in my question. I think its because of those total 9 columns? how do I make them smaller again? sorry for being so bad at css and bootstrap

Comment: Ops I forgot to use @jeremy

Comment: @Jeremy the 9 indeed says 9 columns, so if you want it smaller make it 8 or 7 or 6, the total columns in a row is allways 12 so best practice is to make your label 4 columns if your input is 8 (Cause 4 + 8 = 12)  etc..

Comment: But what If i don't want to use all the 12 columns? I want the inputs to be like 150 width, and if I change the input to like 2 columns there is to much space between the label and input @jeremy

Comment: You don't need to use all 12, but then it won't be 100% of the row width.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to get? Remove the `class="form-inline"` from your form and to your form-group divs add class `row`.

I also added a container around the form to keep it in a good size.

**edit**
I forgot to add `class="col-sm-4"` to the labels and `class="form-control col-sm-8"` to the inputs. So they were not next to eachother.

```css
label{
  text-align: center;
}

h3, .container button{
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
      <h3> Jongere toevoegen </h3>
    <br>
    <form>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-4">Roepnaam:</label>
        <input class="form-control col-sm-8" name="roepnaam" id="roepnaam" placeholder="Roepnaam" type="text">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-4">Tussenvoegsel:</label>
        <input class="form-control col-sm-8" name="tussenvoegsel" id="tussenvoegsel" placeholder="Tussenvoegsel" type="text">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-4">Achternaam:</label>
        <input class="form-control col-sm-8" name="achternaam" id="achternaam" placeholder="Achternaam" type="text">
      </div>

      <div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" name="Add_jongere">Toevoegen</button>
      </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the entire form inside a responsive col, and adjust the label/input widths accordingly...

https://www.codeply.com/go/vdQSHJUalP

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <form class="col-12 col-md-8 mx-auto">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-5 col-sm-3 text-truncate">Roepnaam:</label>
                <input class="form-control col" name="roepnaam" id="roepnaam" placeholder="Roepnaam" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-5 col-sm-3 text-truncate">Tussenvoegsel:</label>
                <input class="form-control col" name="tussenvoegsel" id="tussenvoegsel" placeholder="Tussenvoegsel" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-5 col-sm-3 text-truncate">Achternaam:</label>
                <input class="form-control col" name="achternaam" id="achternaam" placeholder="Achternaam" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-12 text-center">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" name="Add_jongere">Toevoegen</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

`.formcontrol {width: 50%; float:right;}`